# Debian 11 bullseye doesn't create /etc/sanoid folder when running apt install sanoid

Tags: debian, apt, bugs

Debian 11 bullseye doesn't create /etc/sanoid folder when running apt install sanoid.

It's that a bug?

Can I download the /etc folder contents from the github page and expect that the rest of the installation it's ok? Or should I install directly from github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not a bug; see [`/usr/share/doc/sanoid/README.Debian`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/sanoid/-/blob/debian/sid/debian/sanoid.README.Debian):

> To start, copy the example config file in `/usr/share/doc/sanoid/examples/` to `/etc/sanoid/sanoid.conf`.

Upstream instructions refer to `/etc/sanoid/sanoid.defaults.conf`, but the Debian package [ships and expects that in `/usr/share/sanoid`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/sanoid/-/blob/debian/sid/debian/patches/defaults-in-usr-share.patch) — this avoids the risk that users will modify the file.